# Jetpack Compose: AccessibilityInteractionController.java exception

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I released my app to Google Play and I can see a lot of fatal exceptions being logged to crashlytics, the stack trace is:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatableNodeKt.requireCoordinator-64DMado(DelegatableNodeKt.java:295)
       at androidx.compose.ui.semantics.SemanticsNode.findCoordinatorToGetBounds$ui_release(SemanticsNode.kt:356)
       at androidx.compose.ui.semantics.SemanticsNode.getSize-YbymL2g(SemanticsNode.java:115)
       at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.performActionHelper(AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:1358)
       at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.access$performActionHelper(AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:117)
       at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat$MyNodeProvider.performAction(AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.android.kt:2451)
       at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.performAccessibilityActionUiThread(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:612)
       at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.-wrap6(AccessibilityInteractionController.java)
       at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$PrivateHandler.handleMessage(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1228)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6942)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

or

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatableNodeKt.requireCoordinator-64DMado(DelegatableNodeKt.java:295)
       at androidx.compose.ui.semantics.SemanticsNode.findCoordinatorToGetBounds$ui_release(SemanticsNode.kt:356)
       at androidx.compose.ui.semantics.SemanticsNode.getSize-YbymL2g(SemanticsNode.java:115)
       at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.performActionHelper(AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:1358)
       at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.access$performActionHelper(AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:117)
       at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat$MyNodeProvider.performAction(AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.android.kt:2451)
       at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.performAccessibilityActionUiThread(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:708)
       at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.access$500(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:67)
       at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$PrivateHandler.handleMessage(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1327)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6704)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:916)
```

that's all I can see in the logs.. As you can see, the stacktrace does not have any code that belongs to my app, so there's no place where I can put a try/catch for example and I can't even reproduce this.

Any idea on how to fix this or at least reproduce the issue?

This app release was built with compose v1.3, but I could see logs from  1.3-beta as well...
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The following release(s) address this bug.

androidx.compose.ui:ui:**1.4.0-alpha05**

Source: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/258907850